# Order arrays based on references stored in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Weird scenario here but I've come across it.

I have 2 arrays of objects which are for this scenario lets say `actions` and `lines`.

Inside of `actions` I have objects formatted like this:

```
{
    id: 'randomGeneratedId1',
    text: 'Click here',
    url: 'stackoverflow.com'
}
```

Inside of `lines` I have:

```
{
    id: 'randomGeneratedId2',
    text: 'Line 1'
}
```

Finally I have another array which is what stores the order of these... Let's call this the `elementOrder`

```
[
    { id: 'randomGeneratedId1', order: 1 },
    { id: 'randomGeneratedId2', order: 2 }
]
```

Basically what I want to do from the `elementOrder` as referenced above I want to look through both of the `lines` and `actions` array and put them into order inside of this final array so I have a result of an array which has a list of element data and the ids in the order that they are in.

The reason it's turned out like this is because I have a method called `class.line('Line 1').action('Click here', 'stackoverflow.com').line(...).action(...).action(...)` I want the chaining to be unlimited but I need them both in different objects to begin with.

I know that this is possible and I have tried to map it etc but I can't seem to wrap my head around it!

Comment: do you want them to call directly or an array with the wanted order?

Comment: @NinaScholz sorry, what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sort the `elementOrder` array based on `order` field
2. Loop through the sorted `elementOrder` array.
3. For each element in it, search the `actions` and `lines` array to find the match and build the `finalArray` based on this.

Code -

```
var actions = [
  {
    id: 'randomGeneratedId1',
    text: 'Click here',
    url: 'stackoverflow.com'
  }]

var lines = [
  {
    id: 'randomGeneratedId2',
    text: 'Line 1'
  }
]

var elementOrder = [
  { id: 'randomGeneratedId2', order: 2 },
  { id: 'randomGeneratedId1', order: 1 }
]


// this is where you build the final array
var finalArray = elementOrder.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order).map(ele => {
  var action = actions.find(action => ele.id === action.id);
  if (action) {
    return action;
  }
  var line = lines.find(line => ele.id === line.id);
  if (line) {
    return line;
  }
  return ele;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalArray));
// [{"id":"randomGeneratedId1","text":"Click here","url":"stackoverflow.com"},{"id":"randomGeneratedId2","text":"Line 1"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `Map` and call the function chain directly with the wanted functions.

```
var action = [],
    lines = [],
    elementOrder = [],
    map = new Map;

actions.forEach(payload => m.set(payload.id, { type: 'action', payload }));
actions.forEach(payload => m.set(payload.id, { type: 'line', payload }));

elementOrder.reduce((o, { id }) => {
    var data = m.get(id);
    return o[data.type](data.payload.text, data.payload.url)
}, class);
```